# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936

Tags: nodejs, npm

After install Node.js and NPM with commands (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, sudo apt install nodejs` (v16.7.0), `sudo apt install npm`(7.20.3)) in Ubuntu 20.04, I receive message bellow :

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Aula02/aula02.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

Thanks.